# How do designers choose shapes in a design?

Tags: website-design, interface-design, design-principles, user-experience

A lot of times, while browsing through sites like Dribbble, one comes across sites that use shapes. For example, this one:

[image: this example]

Sorry for being naive, but is there a reason behind choosing a particular shape or is it just because it's trending? How does it affect user experience?

Comment: A couple of points of interest.  I use circles a great deal as they create a sense of completeness - one of the earliest symbols for GOD is a circle above an equilateral triangle. As a pattern they can be uniform creating a sense of order or random and playful. Have a look at Jamie Reid and the British punk movement - he used ragged edges and discordant shapes to emphasise rebellion and political discontent. And be careful of Masonic references such as the pyramid, pentagram and single eye - they exist and are deployed for recognition of influence: https://goo.gl/4L7XHP

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Actually there *may be* a great deal of thought put into such usage, well beyond personal preference or some client directive.

---

## Style

- If you know you want a more **friendly**, loose "feel" then you would go with more rounded shapes.
- If you want a more corporate, **serious** appearance, you'd lean towards corners, triangles, and generally hard line shapes.

---

## Placement

Placement and position can be sorted though the *[psychology of eye movement](https://www.fastcodesign.com/90131416/eye-tracking-is-turning-design-into-a-science)* across a design, or *[visual hierarchy](https://www.interaction-design.org/literature/article/visual-hierarchy-organizing-content-to-follow-natural-eye-movement-patterns)* in a design.

- If you want a happy, joyful mood, direct the eye upward and right...
- If you want a more serious, unhappy mood then direct the eye downward and left.

Those sorts of design choices can factor into *where* the shapes are placed.

Much the same way *color* will change the perception of a design, so will placement and usage of these design "shapes" or elements.

---

## Balance

Often general graphic elements can be great tools to improve the overall **balance** of a design.

Looking at the page without the shapes creates a static, non-dynamic, piece with very little eye movement. Which is then somewhat unbalanced due to the position of the large chart graphic in comparison to the block of type next to it (page margins are noticeably unbalanced).

[image]

To create a bit more of a "friendly" appearance, throw in some rounded shapes and use them to offset that margin imbalance at the top of the layout. This also allows the chart graphic to be larger without visually seeming "incorrectly" sized. If it were my design I might play off of the curves in the "2" and "3" since they are existing prominent curves - attempting to mimic or repeat those arcs for the top right shapes. (Repetition can foster continuity and cohesion within a design.)

[image]

However, now the piece is *terribly* imbalanced. So, by adding an additional shape to offset the top right corner, a great deal is done to rebalance the piece overall. Keeping in mind a top-right movement is preferable, the curve of the left shape may be *entirely* intentional to create the almost arrow-like combination of the green shapes. In addition, the gradients on the green shapes further promote an upward right movement.

[image]

So the designer of that piece is....

- using *rounded shapes to be more inviting* overall.
- *directing the eye up and to the right* to promote good feelings...
- use *additional shapes to create overall balance* within the design while promoting eye movement.

Add to this the high contrast (red) figures at the top which are facing left...

So... English reading is left to right, top to bottom... the eye tracks right and downward while reading. But is then naturally drawn to the upper right via the shapes.. then the red figures subtly direct the eye back to the left to start reading again... so the eye is really directed in that layout well in an attempt to maximize the time someone spends viewing the page.

These sorts of usage and placement decisions come with experience and exploration.

*Seemingly* random elements may *not* be random at all... they can serve important purposes even if the reader/viewer is unaware of exactly *what* the purpose may be.

Answer (score 5):

This is probably going to get hammered shut but in brief; the basic shapes, circles, squares and rectangles are invaluable as the fundamental elements of design.

Shapes and curves can provide feeling and emotion to design. A curly-cue feels so different than a right angle.

A circle or blob as a design motif suggests harmony in the simplest way.
However there is a strong design trend towards complex grids and structures.

Alternately, and in response there is strong trend towards simplicity and fundamental natural shapes.

In the 90's it was said that they gave up the grid for the blob but nowadays we see a hybrid.

As our screens are rectangles, curves and circles on screen create a dynamic dialogue between shapes.

Answer (score 4):

This is very opinion based but:

- many times these 'shapes' are derived from the actual logo and/or are part of a branding system. eg. Vodafone's [rhombus system](https://issuu.com/logobr/docs/vodafone_core_master_interactive_gu)
- other times they could be just trending elements
- other times its the clients who cannot buy anything too 'plain' and they feel they should be getting something more 'creative', so designers will need to come up with these things just to fill some white space

Comment: On your 3rd point: today I discussed a book cover design with our intern – your basic "Title, author, picture" setup. I asked if there was "room or reason" for a graphic element, but as there was a good spatial relationship between the elements, we agreed with "no, it would not *add* anything to the design". But hopefully that client is not "afraid" of empty space!

Comment: That 3rd point is so true.