# Is there something as a "funny" font?

Tags: font-recommendation

[Related](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/107628/what-resource-to-learn-about-the-psychological-effects-of-typography)

Matisse ITC is the Scream Queen of fonts, everything says "horror", and you can even pinpoint the source: ragged, slanted letters. So you can induce emotion with fonts.

I was wondering if I count find a "funny" font, the equivalent of canned laughter in sitcoms, and for starter just googled "funny" on a free font site.

Dude, not funny.

It seems to be fairly easy to design a *silly* font (just add rabbit ears for an Easter font, say), but not a *funny* one.
(Comedy Buddy and Twiddlestix I found most convincing.)
Maybe humor is much more individual than horror...

To avoid delving in subjectivity: Is there a font in wide use when it comes to conveying humor, like Matisse ITC for horror (the latter being my personal impression; some sample bias may apply)? (But feel free to put a recommended "funny" font into the comments.)

Comment: Well, to me Matisse ITC is NOT a horror font _at all_. Quite the contrary. The original intention was also [very much non-horror](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/matisse-itc). So your "to avoid subjectivity" falls flat on it's face. I'm afraid _any_ answer will be very subjective.

Comment: Fonts don't really "say" *anything*. It's the overall context of the design that conveys any "mood" or "feeling". Times Roman *can be* as "funny" as Helvetica in the proper context. I will say that the more difficult a font is to read, studies have shown that readers "feel" that any task the type is asking for *seems* more difficult and strenuous. So legibility is imperative regardless of what font you choose.

Comment: I like to look at what movie posters use. So for comedy movies.. I'd just [image search](https://www.google.com/search?q=comedy+movie+posters&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjg2eGi6_f-AhXREVkFHebrBe0Q0pQJegQICxAB&biw=1822&bih=1227&dpr=1) You can see there, sans serif is *very* common for comedy film posters. But.. there are some which use a standard serif. In only a few, very rare, instances is a more ornate display font used.